# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед тире, когда заканчивается придаточная часть?

Tags: пунктуация

Ребята, кто из Города N, если будет желание покататься на лыжах, когда выпадет снег(,) — пишите в Директ.

Answer (score 2):

*Ребята, кто из Города N, если будет желание покататься на лыжах, когда выпадет снег — пишите в Директ.*

Запятую не ставим.

Пояснение

1) ***Будет желание покататься на лЫжах — пишите в Директ.*** Это БСП, тире ставится для обозначения взаимообусловленных отношений.

2) ***Если будет желание покататься на лЫжах — пишите в Директ.*** Это СПП, но тире ставится с той же целью. Тире (вместо запятой) в СПП используется как дополнительный знак (в частности, при разной структуре предложений).

3) ***Если будет желание покататься на лыжах, когда выпадет снЕг — пишите в Директ***.

Тире ставится уже между блоками. Первый блок состоит из придаточного условия и отнесенного к нему придаточного времени.  Но отношения в СПП те же самые, а вот закрывающая запятая не позволит их обозначить.  В устной же речи оба придаточных произносятся в одну фразу.

**А как же правила?!**

Если почитать у Розенталя  про тире в БСП, то мы увидим только простые примеры, но в реальных текстах первая часть может быть сложной. И вот на практике **закрывающую запятую не ставят**. А у Розенталя есть только один пример сложного предложения, причем тоже без запятой: ***Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать.*** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Comment: Классный ответ. Вы меня переубедили. Только вы не полностью объясняете, пришлось доанализировать. И разница в смысле возникает - а это очень интересно. Вот Артём, к примеру, ответ не понял. Значит, те, кто в языке не особо сильно разбирается, точно не поймут. Тут нужно объяснять, как в школе. Лайк вам поставил.

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо, хотя бы вы мне плюсик поставили.

Comment: Будьте добры, объясните, как это объясняют в школе. Правда, и в школе не всегда хорошо объясняют.

Comment: Если бы было написано вот так: «Ребята, кто из Города N, будет желание покататься на лыжах, когда выпадет снег(,) — пишите в Директ.».  То есть я просто убрал подчинительный союз «если»

Answer (score 1):

Запятая, закрывающая придаточное, нужна. Тире её не отменяет.

Смотрите на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire):

> **§ 176.** Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой, которая отделяет главное предложение от предшествующей ему группы придаточных, если надо подчеркнуть распадение единого целого на две части, например:
>
> *Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам* (Крылов).
>
> *Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем* (Добролюбов).